# $array can't print anything

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array

This is my program , I want to let user type a matrix line by line and print the while matrix , but I can't see the matrix

The user will type

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

like this

and I want to let it show

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Perl program

---

```
$Num = 3;

while($Num > 0 )
{
        $Row = <STDIN>;
        $Row = chomp($Row);
        @Row_array = split(" ",$Row);
        push @P_matrix , @Row_array;
        @Row_array = ();
        $Num = $Num - 1;
}

for($i=0;$i<scalar(@P_matrix);$i++)
{
        for($j=0;$j<scalar(@P_matrix[$i]);$j++)
        {
                printf "$d ",$P_matrix[$i][$j];
        }
        print "\n";
}
```

I change the expression => `printf "$d ",$P_matrix[$i][$j];`  to print `$P_matrix[$i][$j]`
but still don't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a multi-dimensional array, you have to use references. Use

```
push @P_matrix, [ @Row_array ];
```

to create the desired structure.

Also, `chomp` does not return the modified string. Simply use

```
chomp $Row;
```

to remove a newline from $Row. Moreover, `chomp` is not needed at all if you `split` on `' '`.

`printf` uses `%` as the formatting character, not `$`.

You can use `Data::Dumper` to inspect complex data structures. Use `strict` and `warnings` to help you avoid common problems. Here is how I would write your program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Dumper;

my @p_matrix;

push @p_matrix , [ split ' ' ] while <>;

warn Dumper \@p_matrix;

for my $i (0 .. $#p_matrix)
  {
      for my $j (0 .. $#{ $p_matrix[$i] })
        {
            printf '%d ', $p_matrix[$i][$j];
        }
      print "\n";
  }
```

Comment: May I ask you does scalar($p_matrix[$i]) have any syntax problem ?  when I replace $#{ $p_matrix[$i] } of it , it can run correctly ...
What is the correct syntax of scalar($p_matrix[$i])?

Comment: @user2131116: `$p_matrix[$i]` is not an array, it is an array reference. You have to dereference it before you can use `scalar`: `scalar @{ $p_matrix[$i] }`. But `scalar` is not needed in comparison, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost please use `use strict; use warnings;`

Issues in your code:

1. You have a single dimensional array, but your are trying to access
   it like two dimensional array. In order to make 2 dimensional array push the array reference of `Row_array` in `@P_matrix` as `[@Row_array]`.
2. Where is `$d` defined? declare `$d` as `my $d` or `our $d` if you mean `$d` as scalar variable.
   **OR**
   For using `%d`, use need `sprintf`. Please read [this](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html).

Comment: I have a little confuse , does not %d already build in perl , why declare $d as my $d ?

Comment: my bad. Editing the answer. I thought `%d` as `HASH`.

Comment: @KrishnachandraSharma You are probably correct that he is trying to use `printf "%d "`. But he is not using warnings, so he doesn't get an "uninitialized" warning for the non-existant `$d` variable. Nor is he using strict which would have prevented the whole problem.